# Syntax for pointers to a structure

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, syntax

When declaring a pointer to a struct, both the following code snippets compile without error:

A)

```
struct Foo
{
int data;
Foo* temp;   // line in question
}
```

B)

```
struct Foo
{
int data;
struct Foo* temp;  //line in question
}
```

What is the significance to repeating the word "struct" in the declaration of the struct pointer (as in (B))?  Are there any differences compared to not doing so (as in (A))?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: They both have the same meaning. It is up to you whether or not you want to repeat the keyword `struct` while writing `struct Foo* temp;`. That is, `struct Foo* temp;` and `Foo* temp;` have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `struct` keyword **must be used** for declaring structure variables, but it is ***optional*** in C++.

For example, consider the following examples:

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    Foo* temp; // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
};
int main()
{
    Foo a;  // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    struct Foo* temp;   // Works in both C and C++
};
int main()
{
    struct Foo a; // Works in both C and C++
    return 0;
}
```

In the above examples, `temp` is a data member that is a *pointer to non-const `Foo`*.